# IS IT ALLOWED TO READ SEXUAL STUFF

Tags: sexuality

Is it allowed to read sexual stuff or erotica,
If a man reads it, but he doesn't act upon it or speak of it, or doesn't even think of it, but the words give him sexual pleasure, and if he doesn't do sins after it?
In this case it should be permissible right?

Comment: Dear brother/sister, please get married as soon as possible. After that, you won't have any need to ask such questions.

Answer (score 1):

Let me reply to your question by mention as similar question-answer; Question:

> Is reading a sexually arousing story permissible (based on Islam)?

Answer:
It is forbidden for single people in general; But reading sexual stories is not a problem in itself according to the Shari'a, but if it arouses lust, it is not permissible, reading these stories will cause corruption over time.

Of note, the mentioned answer/Fatwas is based on Ayatollah Khamenei

[Reference](https://article.tebyan.net/459011/)

Answer (score 1):

It is not permissible at all.

In Chapter 24, Verse 30 of the Quran, Allah SWT says, “Say to the believing men that they should lower their gaze and guard their modesty: that will make for greater purity for them: And Allah is well acquainted with all that they do.”

Firstly, Allah SWT is the All-Knowing; he knows what’s in our minds and hearts at all times. The true believe would feel ashamed to read such immoral content knowing that Allah is aware of their actions.

In Chapter 17, Verse 32, He says, “And do not approach unlawful sexual intercourse. Indeed, it is ever an immorality and is evil as a way.”

This includes reading sexual content as one does not have control over what influences him or her, and reading such stuff will gradually cause whatever is read to be normalized in one’s mind.

For fatwas, please visit the follow links:

- [Ruling on reading sexual content](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/2252/ruling-on-reading-stories-with-sexual-content-and-looking-at-dirty-pictures)
- [Ruling on reading books about intercourse](https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/52631)